# Angular - How to read/retrieve component's HTML template before it's rendered

Tags: angular

Is there a way to read or retrieve component self's HTML template before it's being rendered?
basically just need to read some original HTML data ideally in constructor. (e.g. trying to read the component A's template HTML content inside its constructor)

I have tried component ComponentFactoryResolver, reflectComponentType, ElementRef but seeming cannot find away to retrieve the HTML template content

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using elementRef?

```
constructor(private myElement: ElementRef) {
this.myElement.nativeElement // <- your direct element reference
}
```

Comment: tried it, constructor seems only showing the component's directive and not the template content

Comment: WHY are you trying to read the template?

Comment: I want to add some metadata and read it to set up some vars. There are many ways to approach this and I just wonder if retrieving HTML content is possible